Automorphism of order 2 of $D_q$
Let $q\geq 3$ be a prime number and $D_q$ be the Dihedral Group of order $2q$. Find all automorphism of $D_q$ of order $2$.
I tried this using a 'generic' automorphism $\varphi$ such that $\varphi(r)=sr^k$ and $\varphi(s)=sr^j$ for some $k$ and $j$, but I don't know what else I should do.

An automorphism preserves the order of an element, so a rotation of order $q$ should map onto another...

$D_q$ is centerless,  hence equal to its inner automorphism group.   There's $q+1$ elements of order $2.$  So are their associated inner automorphisms.   Usually $D_n $ has some outer automorphisms.   It remains to see if there are any of order $2.$

Sorry,  there's $q$ inner automorphisms of order $2.$  Since $q$ is odd, none of the rotations are order $2.$

You have been  given a number of hints now. What developments did they give you?

Hint: You can also use, that the automorphism group of $D_n$ for $n\ge 3$ is isomorphic to
$$
{\rm Aut}(D_n)\cong C_n\rtimes U(n),
$$
of order $n\phi(n)$, where $U(n)=(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^{\times}$ is the group of units of the ring $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$. This has been shown in the reference below:
Prove that $| \operatorname{Aut}(D_n)|= n\phi(n)$.
For $n=q>2$ prime, $U(q)$ is cyclic of order $\phi(q)=q-1$.
Hence we have
$$
{\rm Aut}(D_q)\cong C_q\rtimes C_{q-1}.
$$
